# Why does AutoMapper validation not work if an object Property exists?

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

If I call the `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` function of AutoMapper it should throw an exception for each property of a mapped class, that uses a type that is not mapped. It seems like this does not happen, if at least one of the properties is of type `object`.

I understand that AutoMapper cannot check, if everything that can be assigned to a `object` property is mapped, but I assumed it would still throw an exception for other properties that use unmapped types.

If I have these simple classes:

```
public class RootLevel
{
    public object ObjectProperty { get; set; }
    public SecondLevel SecondLevel { get; set; }
}

public class RootLevelDto
{
    public object ObjectProperty { get; set; }
    public SecondLevelDto SecondLevel { get; set; }
}

public class SecondLevel
{
}

public class SecondLevelDto
{
}
```

And I (incorrectly) only map the `RootLevel` class and try to execute this code:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<RootLevel, RootLevelDto>();
});
config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
var mapper = new Mapper(config);

var source = new RootLevel
{
    SecondLevel = new SecondLevel()
};
var mapped = mapper.Map<RootLevelDto>(source);
```

I would expect the call to `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` to throw an exception because the type `SecondLevel` is not mapped. But I only get the exception as soon as I call `mapper.Map<RootLevelDto>(source)`, and only if my source object actually has a non-`null` value in the `SecondLevel` property.

If I comment out the `ObjectProperty` properties, the call to `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` throws the expected exception.

This lead to an issue where I discovered missing mappings too late, because the value was always `null` during testing.

Is there a way to avoid this issue, other than getting rid of the `object` properties?

Comment: Just speculating, but perhaps because `SecondLevel` and `SecondLevelDto` are empty classes?

Comment: They are only empty classes in this simplified example, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug, solved now. Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

A *fragile* workaround is to declare the `object` properties at the end of the class definition.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can confirm that the MyGet build and reordering the Properties both fix the issue.

Comment: The docs say "However, starting with .NET 7, the ordering is deterministic based upon the metadata ordering in the assembly." But my advice would be to simply use the MyGet build.